# How to pass bash array variable to jq not file

Tags: bash, jq

I want to modify my json and add more fields

**current JSON:**

```json
{
  "cubes": [
    {
      "no": 1,
      "plant_number": "1050-0"
    },
    {
      "no": 2,
      "plant_number": "2050-0"
    },
    {
      "no": 3,
      "plant_number": "3050-0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add new field and output should look like

**expected output:**

```json
{
  "no": 1,
  "plant_number": "1050-0",
  "1050-0":"1.1.1.1"
}
{
  "no": 2,
  "plant_number": "2050-0",
  "2050-0":"2.2.2.2"
}
{
  "no": 3,
  "plant_number": "3050-0",
  "3050-0":"3.3.3.3"
}
```

These IPs suppose to get extract by bash so I created script like

*first try:*
I can add static ip like below

```
jq  '.cubes[]| {no,plant_number} | . + {(.plant_number): "0.0.0.0"} ' my.json
```

It results in following JSON

```json
{
  "no": 1,
  "plant_number": "1050-0",
  "1050-0","0.0.0.0"
}
{
  "no": 2,
  "plant_number": "2050-0",
  "2050-0":"0.0.0.0"
}
{
  "no": 3,
  "plant_number": "3050-0",
  "3050-0":"0.0.0.0"
}
```

*second try:*

```
# Here for sake of simplicity declaration is like this otherwise its function which return array
declare -a ips=('1.1.1.1' '2.2.2.2' '3.3.3.3');
jq  '.cubes[]| {no,plant_number} | . + {(.plant_number): $ips} ' my.json
```

its giving error

```
jq: 1 compile error
```

*third try:*

```
declare -a ips=('1.1.1.1' '2.2.2.2' '3.3.3.3');
jq  --arg ips $ips '.cubes[]| {no,plant_number} | . + {(.plant_number): $ips} ' my.json
```

This results in following

```json
{
  "no": 1,
  "plant_number": "1050-0",
  "1050-0": "1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3"
}
{
  "no": 2,
  "plant_number": "2050-0",
  "2050-0": "1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3"
}
{
  "no": 3,
  "plant_number": "3050-0",
  "3050-0": "1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3"
}
```

How can I dynamically assign values to array?

Comment: The expected output is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @choroba sorry I hand prepared json, main intention is to add field with ip

Comment: I assume you want, e.g., `{"no": 1, "plant_number": "1050-0", "1050-0": "1.1.1.1"}`?

Comment: @chepner correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (easily) pass an array from shell into an array in jq. But as you are dealing with (strictly formatted) IPs you can pass them as one string (`"${ips[*]}"`) and split it into an array from within jq (`$ips / " "`).

```sh
declare -a ips=('1.1.1.1' '2.2.2.2' '3.3.3.3');
jq --arg ips "${ips[*]}" '
  [.cubes, $ips / " "] | transpose[] as [$c,$ip] | $c + {($c.plant_number): $ip}
' my.json
```

```json
{
  "no": 1,
  "plant_number": "1050-0",
  "1050-0": "1.1.1.1"
}
{
  "no": 2,
  "plant_number": "2050-0",
  "2050-0": "2.2.2.2"
}
{
  "no": 3,
  "plant_number": "3050-0",
  "3050-0": "3.3.3.3"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ryAgMJP7Qr)